# How to properly set the path for executing a child powershell script?

Tags: c#, powershell

**Resolved**: the solution to below is to use the following Join-Path:
`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path (pwd) "MyAssembly.dll")) | out-null`

**Original question**:

I have powershell scripts and an assembly file placed as follows:

```
D:\path1\script1.ps1
D:\path2\script2.ps1
D:\path2\MyAssembly.dll
```

Within D:\path1\script1.ps1 I need to call D:\path2\script2.ps1. Then, script2.ps1 will in turn load some C# assemblies that are already placed in the D:\path2 folder. I was under the impression that if I do either Set-Location or Push-Location then the working directory would be properly set for anything that happens within script2.ps1.

script1.ps1 looks like this:

```
$otherpath = "D:\path2"

Set-Location -Path $otherpath

Push-Location -Path $otherpath

.\script2.ps1
```

script2.ps1 looks like this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll") | out-null
```

However, when I'm in D:\path1, I execute script1.ps1 as follows, and then I get a FileNotFound exception:

```
D:\path1>powershell .\script1.ps1

Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly
'file:///D:\path1\MyAssembly.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
specified."
At D:\path2\script2.ps1:1 char:1
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("MyAssembly.dll") | out-null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException
```

How do I set the path correctly such that when I call script1.ps1 from D:\path1 then the environment has D:\path2 set properly as the working directory for all the calls to assemblies in D:\path2?

Comment: What if you change MyAssembly.dll to .\MyAssembly.dll? Or even better yet give it the full path explicitly?

Comment: adding .\ doesn't work, same error. However, using `(Join-Path (pwd) $assemblyName)` does work. Thanks for the tip! I'll update the question above with the answer. If you type up this answer I'll also select it.

Comment: Nah, you figured it out. You post the answer of what fixed it if you want and after some period of time (I forget how long) you can accept it.

Comment: 2 days, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following Join-Path:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path (pwd) "MyAssembly.dll")) | out-null
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path (pwd) "MyAssembly.dll")) | out-null` will work as long as there is no change to the working directory inside script2.

The alternative would be to use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` which will always give the full path of the current script. You could use it like this:

`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) "MyAssembly.dll")) | out-null`

Comment: I would have added this as a comment but I don't have the required rep.